# filter not trigger the change event from text input

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I would like to understand, why the change deduction is not works, on `keyup` while integrate the filter using the input value.

**when the key ups, I am getting no of empty string popups to prevent the filter.**

here is the code:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <p>register works!</p>
  <input aria-label="filter text" (keyup)="filterIt($event)" type="text" />
  <div *ngFor="let student of filterStudent(); trackBy:identify">{{student}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  students = ['Yamini', 'Surat', 'Arif', 'Madura'];

  filterStudent(str = '') {
    console.log(str)
    const filtered = this.students.filter((student) =>
      student.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(str.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
    return filtered;
  }

  filterIt($event: Event) {
    const event = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.filterStudent(event.value);
  }

  identify(_index: number, name: string) {
    return name;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Live Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xagtm2?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always calling `filterStudent()` from template that always returns the same value.

Avoid calling methods withing template.

As an option you can create a property `filteredStudents` and update it on `keyUp` event:

**ts**

```
filteredStudents = this.students;
...
filterIt($event: Event) {
  const event = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  this.filteredStudents = this.filterStudent(event.value);
}
```

**html**

```
*ngFor="let student of filteredStudents; trackBy:identify">
```

[**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9bgw7j?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

---

Another option might be using Observable

**html**

```
*ngFor="let student of filteredStudents$ | async..."
```

**ts**

```
query$ = new BehaviorSubject('');

filteredStudents$ = this.query$.pipe(
  map(query => this.filterStudent(query))
);

filterIt($event: Event) {
  const event = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  this.query$.next(event.value);
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bsdmvd?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**

Comment: It works. But each time I return the `filter`. also, Can I use this kind of `filter` over `pipe` ?

Comment: I added the second example with rxjs and `pipe`